# Primitive solvable group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Let $G$ be a finite solvable group. Suppose that $G=HN$ for all minimal normal subgroups $N$ of $G$. To show that $H = G$ or $G$ is primitive

If $N$ is a minimal subgroup of $G$ then $N$ is an elementary abelian $p$-group because $G$ is solvable. Thus $H\cap N \unlhd N$, so either $N=N\cap H$ or $N\cap H = 1_G$.

If $N=N\cap H$ then $N\leq H$ so that $H=G$. If $N\cap H = 1_G$, then $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$. I need to show that Core$_G(H) = \displaystyle\bigcap\limits_{g\,\in G} H^g = \{1_G\}$. I'm not sure how to proceed.

Comment: This is very confused. The second paragraph should start "Let $N$ be a minimal normal subgroup of $G$." A maximal subgroup cannot be equal to $G$. You have two cases. If $N = N \cap H$ then $H=G$, which is one of the required options. The second case is $N \cap H=1$, and then $H$ is a maximal subgroup of $G$. As a hint, note that if ${\rm Core}_G(H) \ne 1$, then it contains a minimal normal subgroup of $G$.

Comment: I'm unable to see why if Core$_G(H) \neq 1_G$ then it contains a minimal normal subgroup of $G$. The rest of the proof will follow since if $P$ is the minimal normal subgroup of $G$ contained in Core$_G(H)$ then $P\leq H$ but $G=HP$ so $G=H$ contradicting $H$ being a maximal subgroup

Comment: But surely that is completely obvious? Just choose a smallest nontrivial normal subgroup contained in it.

Comment: My bad. I did not use the fact that Core$_G(H) \unlhd G$. So if Core$_G(H) \neq 1_G$ and no other non-trivial normal subgroups of $G$ are properly contained in Core$_G(H)$, then it is a minimal normal subgroup of $G$ and we get the contradiction. If there are non-trivial normal subgroups contained in Core$_G(H)$, choosing the smallest such gives you a minimal normal subgroup in $G$, and produces the contradiction above. Thanks a lot